# how to load images from resources folder into android listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a 200 images in resource folder i named them as `name_1.png`,`name_2.png`. and I have a array in that I have few numbers such as `2, 4 , 6 ,30 , 40 ... and so on`.

I want to load image and text view into android `listview` and show the images according to the number from resource folder.

For this I have created a `activity class` and `image adapter class` for `custom list view`.

I am able to show the `text view` data but not the images according to the array data numbers .

can any one suggest me how to do this. I am thinking that I have to write code in `getview` method to change the image.

This is `getview` method that I tried

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);


    TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtype);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvnumber);
    ImageView i1= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivlfirst);
    //int i = Integer.parseInt("normal_"+mStrings.get(position)+".png");

i1.setBackgroundResource("normal_"+mStrings.get(position)+".png");
    tv1.setText(mStrings1.get(position));
    tv2.setText(mStrings.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: in resource folder means in `res/drawable/` right?

Comment: please make int array of image.

Comment: well dipak sir please can you tell how to that with some code ,it will be great help sir

Comment: for image under res folder i have show u sollution check that

Answer (score 0):

You can not easily do that when your images are in the res folder since each resource is accessed by an int id.

You should consider to place your images into the assets folder which you can access like a regular file system. Have a look at the AssetManager.

Comment: ok sir i have moved my images into assets folder now how showed i do, can you show me some code sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to fetch images from `assets`:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("normal_"+mStrings.get(position)+".png");
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "resourceName");
i1.setBackgroundDrawable(d); //i1 is your imageView
```

hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just do as given below in your **getView()** method

```
 String yourimagename="normal_"+ mStrings.get(position);   // In this no need of image extension like .png,.jpg etc

 int  resImgId= YourActivityName.this.getResources().getIdentifier("Your Package Name:drawable/" +yourimagename, null, null);
```

or try this

```
 int  resImgId= YourActivityName.this.getResources().getIdentifier("Your Package Name:drawable/" +yourimagename, null, null);
```

or try this

```
 int  resImgId= context.getResources().getIdentifier("Your Package Name:drawable/" +yourimagename, null, null); 
 i1.setImageResource(resImgId);
```

Comment: same error bro error is : The method getResources() is undefined for the type ImageAndTextAdapter

Comment: mStrings.get(position) what it returns String value or integer value and join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite for discussion we will discuss more there rather than comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image from drawable folder based on its name (getting resource id from resource name) use **public int [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (String name, String defType, String defPackage)** which returns a resource identifier for the given resource name like:

```
 int image = getResources().getIdentifier(image_name, "drawable",getPackageName());
 ImageView i1= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivlfirst);
 i1.setBackgroundResource(image);
```

---

For your particular case you can use:

```
i1.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier("normal_"+mStrings.get(position), "drawable",getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take One `Integer array` for `R.drawable.imageView1......200` and pass its value Like

```
    private Integer[] Imgid = {R.drawable.imageview1,....,200  };
    i1.setBackgroundResource(Imgid[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve all the images that are in a folder that you don't actually need to be accessible from the R.drawable call, as mentioned by GAMA you can use `activity.getAssets` call, it would be something like this in Kotlin:

```
private fun getAllImagesFromAssets(activity: Activity): Map<String, Bitmap> {
        val images = mutableMapOf<String, Bitmap>()
        activity.assets.list(imageDatabaseAssetDirectory)?.forEach { imageName ->
            activity.assets.open("$imageDatabaseAssetDirectory/$imageName").apply {
                images[imageName] = getBitmapFromInputStream(this)
            }
        }
        return images
    }
```