# How to retrieve images from within the APK? (BASIC)

Tags: java, android, image, apk

I'm a newbie and really would like some help with finding out how to retrieve files from my assets folder within my APK for a live wallpaper. Basically what is the code or what is the correct file path formatting if I wanted to retrieve a file from my assets folder (images).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10863242/529543

Comment: Have a look at [getting drawables from the asset folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5082672/2636001)

Comment: What do you want to do with it? As in, do you need an actual file, or is a drawable enough?

Answer (score 1):

Open the apk with `Winrar` or anyother zip extracter. Go to `res->drawable-??dpi` folder. There will be all the images used in the apk.

?? means xhdpi or hdpi or mdpi

**`Programatically`** it can be done by this code snippet.

```
Drawable getImage = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("Cloths/btn_no.png"), null);
```